# Ansible playbook gating facts in a temporary folder

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

There are a useful ansible command that gathing the facts and store them, like this,

```
ansible -m setup --tree out/ all
```

But how could do it by ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini ? just store the facts but not actually run the playbook and only for diagnosis.

Thanks
James.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange request, but...

To execute only fact-gathering part of your playbook you can execute it with a tag that doesn't exist:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini -vv -t zzzz myplaybook.yml
```

This will dump gathered facts to stdout.

If you want to store it into file, you should do something like this:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json \
  ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini -t zzzz myplaybook.yml 2>/dev/null \
  | jq '.plays[].tasks[].hosts[]' > tmp_hosts_facts
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I want to use the ansible-cmdb, https://github.com/fboender/ansible-cmdb, to output something.